Refreshlink on Dataverse table from Access Database not working
I have a button on an Access form that calls the subroutine below. The database has external links to Dataverse tables. The idea of the routine is to refresh the links to the Dataverse tables and then refresh the form. The subroutine completes normally, and the "Tables Refreshed" message appears without error. However, the tables are not actually refreshed.  The last table is called tblProjectsDataverse and contains project descriptions from the table which then appear in a list on the form. After I run the routine, I manually open the linked table (tblProjectsDataverse) and new projects added from a different source to the Dataverse table are not included. If I manually run Refresh Links by right clicking the linked table on the Navigation pane and selecting Refresh Links, the table is updated correctly. I don't know why the .RefreshLink method in VBA would work differently than Refresh Link manually.
Private Sub cmdRefresh_Click()

Dim dbsCurrent As Database
Dim tbl As TableDef

Set dbsCurrent = CurrentDb

    For Each tbl In CurrentDb.TableDefs()
        If tbl.Attributes = dbAttachedTable Then
                
            If Right(tbl.Name, 9) = "Dataverse" Then
        
            MsgBox (tbl.Connect)
            MsgBox (tbl.Name)
            tbl.RefreshLink
            
            End If
            
        End If
                
    Next tbl
    
    Me.Refresh
    
    MsgBox ("Tables Refreshed")

End Sub


The two msgbox lines produces the following when the routine is run:


I've tried using the .RefreshLink method and the connection string seems to be correct according to what others have posted.

Try explicitly declaring DAO objects: DAO.TableDef, DAO.Database.

What happens if you try Me.Requery instead of Me.Refresh?

@June7 Good thinking.  I hadn't considered that.  I just gave it a try and it did not correct the issue. Thank you though.

@HansUp The Me.Refresh is only to refresh the form after the table links are refreshed.  I've already narrowed down the issue to the table links not being refreshed. However, I gave it a try and also did not have the correct result. Thanks for the suggestion.

@HansUp Sorry for the confusion.  I'm using tbl.RefreshLink (I think equivalent to TableDef.RefreshLink) during the loop to refresh the links to the Dataverse tables. I use Me.Refresh after the loop to refresh the Access form.

@HansUp I was curious about that too so I tried it after adding records to the table from a secondary source and checked to make sure the records exist in the Dataverse table. Then I opened the linked table directly as you suggested.  The records are not there. Then, when I Refresh Link the linked table directly from the Navigation pane they show up in the linked table.  However, running this code to perform the RefreshLink does not result in new records showing up.

Those details made me realize I was headed in the wrong direction.  Sorry about that.  I encourage you to add that information to the question.

@HansUp Thank you for your help. I try to provide all the details necessary without overwhelming with information.  Much appreciated.

Try tbl.Connect=tbl.Connect before Refreshlink. And set Form.recordsource or requery form recordset.

@ValNik I appreciate the idea.  I gave the tbl.Connect=tbl.Connect a try.  I see what you're thinking there.  Good idea but it did not solve the problem.  I'm trying to break down the issue and isolate the problem.  I've created a new, separate database recreating that form and re-linking the table.  The issue remains.  I'll need to take up the problem in the morning.  You're help is much appreciated.

I have RefrshLink code for SQLServer tables and it works just fine. Unfortunately, don't have DataVerse so cannot test. DataVerse is cloud-based? Perhaps that is at root of issue.

@June7 You may be correct.  Dataverse is the Azure-like database used in the Power Platform products. If you have Office 365 then you probably have access to Dataverse.  I do appreciate all of the suggestions from you and the rest of the community.
